# getTextContent() issue in w3c and apache

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have used org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent() metthod to get the text value, the same is working fine in Eclipse. When we run it as stanalone, it is taking :class org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl and failing. Please advice on how to get org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent() at runtime.

Comment: What you say makes no sense, if in the coed you imported org.w3c.dom.Node, then that is what will be used. Please post some code and the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) is an interface. [`org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementImpl.html) is an implementation of that interface (really, an implementation of [`org.w3c.dom.Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), a subinterface of `Node`). There are other implementations. If you write a program that uses `Node`, then when you run it, you will actually be using one of the implementations.

It seems that `DeferredElementImpl` does not implement `getTextContent()` properly. Although it's hard to be sure of that, given that you haven't said what the actual problem was.

It seems that in Eclipse, you are using some implementation other than `DeferredElementImpl`, and that implementation implements `getTextContent()` properly. On my installation of Eclipse, i get a [`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/ElementImpl.html) if i create an element in the normal way.

`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl` is the standard implementation bundled in the Sun JRE. If you are getting a different implementation, it is because you have a non-standard XML parser on your classpath. That is perfectly fine, but it's something you should be aware of. If you examine your standalone application's classpath, you should find a parser that isn't there when you run in Eclipse.